# Powershell remoting: inconsistent connectivity

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

How is it that one Powershell command works on a remote machine but not the other from the same console?

1. PS C:> Get-Service -Name WinRM -ComputerName win8

   Status   Name               DisplayName
   ------   ----               -----------
   Running  WinRM              Windows Remote Management (WS-Manag...
2. PS C:> Get-Counter '\Paging File(*)\% Usage' -ComputerName win8
   Get-Counter : Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is offline.
   At line:1 char:1

   - Get-Counter '\Paging File(*)\% Usage' -ComputerName win8
   - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCount 
     erCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-Service and Get-Counter use a different remoting layer for -ComputerName.  Invoke-Command -ComputerName uses the WinRM remoting layer, Get-Service (I believe) is a remote registry call.  Get-Counter is a DCOM call, I believe over WMI.

It's a pretty good rule of thumb that if you don't know that a cmdlet with -ComputerName in it is using the PowerShell remoting layer, it's probably not.   Many cmdlets had -ComputerName in V1 of PowerShell, and many other remoting layers are more efficient than WinRM, so many -ComputerName parameters use their own layer.